# inserting new values in dicts stored in a list of dicts

Tags: python

```
[{'name': None, 'price': None, 'shares': None},
 {'name': None, 'price': None, 'shares': None},
  {'name': None, 'price': None, 'shares': None},
  {'name': None, 'price': None, 'shares': None},
```

I have a list of dicts like this and 3 lists that I zipped into one that has the values Id like to go into the corresponding dict.

I thought I could just go through the list and use a for loop to update the values but what ends up happening is that every dict is updated to the last item in the list of values

Comment: Would be nice to see what you're trying to insert, and how you want it to look like.

Comment: Also, you probably don't need to pre-initialise an empty structure as you do.

Comment: What do the three lists look like?

Comment: If your dictionaries are all ending up the same, there's a good chance they're all the same dictionary. How are you constructing that list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using your list of dicts.  But as cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ noted, you don't need to initialize the empty structure.  Here are two solutions, one with and one without pre-initialization.

Example data:

```
names = ["Alice", "Bob", "Carol", "Eve"]
price = [1.00, 2.01, 3.02, 4.03]
shares = [10, 50, 80, 100]
data = zip(names, price, shares)
```

With pre-initialization:

```
frame = [{'name': None, 'price': None, 'shares': None},
         {'name': None, 'price': None, 'shares': None},
         {'name': None, 'price': None, 'shares': None},
         {'name': None, 'price': None, 'shares': None}]

dlist = list(data)

for i, d in enumerate(frame):
    for j, k in enumerate(d.keys()):
        d[k] = dlist[i][j]

frame
[{'name': 'Alice', 'price': 1.0, 'shares': 10},
 {'name': 'Bob', 'price': 2.01, 'shares': 50},
 {'name': 'Carol', 'price': 3.02, 'shares': 80},
 {'name': 'Eve', 'price': 4.03, 'shares': 100}]
```

Without pre-initialization:

```
fields = ["name", "price", "shares"]
[{k:v for k, v in zip(fields, d)} for d in data]
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this is exactly what I was looking for.